# private method "through_reflection" popping up for Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am experiencing this error a lot in my app, and can't find documentation on in it in ChangeLog or elsewhere.  Not sure if this is a Rails bug...or, my smelly code.

I experienced it once where a through association was defined before the parent has_many.  I also seem to be able to resolve the error by changing .each to .find_each.  I resolve it on one instance by refactoring eager loading.  I also had it occur calling .present? on query object rather than .any?.  I can also resolve by skipping the has_many through and just chaining scopes.

Even more interesting...I don't get these errors on Heroku in production.  Same environments.  Rails 5.2 (master), ruby 2.5.

The error always results when loading a has_many through association.  Important to note...they all worked fine prior to 5.2.  Also, interestingly...the query usually works fine in the console...but, not in the browser.

```
private method `through_reflection' called for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyThroughAssociation:0x00007ff0df3590a8>
```

Does anyone have any info pertaining to this rails error?

Comment: This error is directly related to the bullet gem...I'm still digging in to this.

Answer (score 2):

updating bullet to 5.7.1 fixed this